# shutil.copy/copy2 while file is open results in exception "[Errno 13] permission denied"

Tags: python, copy, permission-denied

I want to script a small backup software, so I decided to trigger to the "modified" & "created" event. Everything works fine, except the copyjob for an opened file.

Example:

- When I create an Word file, it will be created
- When I open the Word file, modify it, and save it. I get the exception: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Here is my code snipped:

```
        if os.path.isfile(event.src_path):
            if os.path.exists(destinationFilePath) and event.event_type == 'modified':
                os.remove(destinationFilePath)
            
            #We need a short sleep, because the file may be in use by windows creation routine
            time.sleep(1)
            shutil.copy2(event.src_path, destinationFilePath)
            logging.info(f"File created: {destinationFilePath}")
```

I have also tried the copy, copy2 and the way with subprocess->copy, but also get the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shutil.copyfile` (instead of `.copy2`) as this method copies the contents of the source file to the destination file instead of copying the file in itself. Therefore  you can use the copying even if the file is currently open!

Keep in mind, that this could cause the file to have non up-to-date data when being copied (is there might be multiple processes writing at the same time)!

**EDIT:**

```
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_MAX_TRIES):
        try:
            shutil.copyfile(event.src_path, destinationFilePath)
            logging.info(f"File created: {destinationFilePath}")
            break
        except PermissionError:
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Specify / Tweak with the sleeping time a bit. Furthermore, set a `NUMBER_OF_MAX_TRIES` variable. Maybe start with 10ish and debug how many tries it needs?

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work too. I get the same exception.

Comment: Maybe try to add a `try: ... except PermissionError:` block with a small waiting time.. I will add a small snippet.

Comment: Seems to work, thank you! :)
I've had to add 

hint:
if not event.src_path.startswith("~"):

for Office files.